# Excel VBA How do I Read Data from a Text file 5 lines at a time and do until end of file?

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with VBA. I would like to read in ONLY 5 lines of data at a time, process the data, ClearContents and repeat until the end of the file.

This is what I have written but it is not working:

```
Dim FilePath As String, Dim Start As Integer

FilePath = "C:\Users\Main\temp3.txt"

Open FilePath For Input As 3
row_number = 5

Do Until EOF(3)

For Start = 1 To 5  

    Line Input #36, LineFromFile
    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")

    Range("A2").Value = LineItems(0)
    Range("B2").Value = LineItems(1)
    Range("C2").Value = LineItems(2)
    Range("D2").Value = LineItems(3)
    Range("E2").Value = LineItems(4)
    Range("F2").Value = LineItems(5)
    Range("G2").Value = LineItems(6)

    row_number = row_number + 1  

Next Start

'Process data here

Range("ClearContents").ClearContents

Loop

Close #3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Thisworkbook.sheets("<nameofsheet>").Range("A2").value` or `Thisworkbook.sheets(<indexofsheet>).Range("A2").value` instead of `Range("A2").value`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MikeW unfortunally I haven't enough rep to comment a post yet. So as far as I know I had to formulate an answer to interact at all. In addition I think it's an answer (even if I formulated it as a question). If you understand my argument, would you resign your delete request (of course only if it was yours)?

Comment: I understand that you can't make a comment.  Frustrating.  If you think it's the answer, then just edit and make it less of a question, otherwise it appears to be a helpful comment of something that may work or may not.

Comment: I changed the formulation of the answer. Hope it worked because it seems while doing so my question has been deleted. But now it's there again. Wierd, and a bit frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested)

```
Sub Tester()

    Const BLOCK_SIZE = 5
    Const START_ROW As Long = 2

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim LineFromFile As String, arr
    Dim rowNum As Long, lineNum As Long

    FilePath = "C:\Users\Main\temp3.txt"

    Open FilePath For Input As #1
    rowNum = START_ROW
    lineNum = 0

    Do Until EOF(1)

        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
        lineNum = lineNum + 1

        arr = Split(LineFromFile, ",")

        ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNum, 1).Resize(1, 7).Value = arr

        If lineNum = BLOCK_SIZE Then
            'Process data here
            Range("ClearContents").ClearContents
            rowNum = START_ROW
            lineNum = 0
        Else
            rowNum = rowNum + 1
        End If

    Loop

    Close #3

End Sub
```